# Twilio incoming call is not working in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-programmable-voice

I am working on Twilio programmable voice SDK. I integrated it with the help of [documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/sdks/ios) and [GitHub SDK](https://github.com/twilio/video-quickstart-ios). I can make a call from iOS to any number. It works fine.

The issue is on receiving a call on Twilio number. I did everything that was mentioned in Twilio installation documentation and GitHub SDK, but its not working.

here is the code:

```
@import PushKit;
@import CallKit;
@import TwilioVoice;
@import UserNotifications;
static NSString  * kAccessToken = @"";
 NSString * phoneNumber = @"";
NSString * newToken = @"";
static NSString *const kTwimlParamTo = @"to";

static NSInteger const kRegistrationTTLInDays = 365;

NSString * const kCachedDeviceToken = @"CachedDeviceToken";
NSString * const kCachedBindingTime = @"CachedBindingTime";


@interface RCTCallPackageModule () <TVONotificationDelegate, TVOCallDelegate, CXProviderDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate, AVAudioPlayerDelegate , PushKitEventDelegate, PKPushRegistryDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, weak) id<PushKitEventDelegate> pushKitEventDelegate;

@property (nonatomic, strong) void(^incomingPushCompletionCallback)(void);
@property (nonatomic, strong) void(^callKitCompletionCallback)(BOOL);
@property (nonatomic, strong) TVODefaultAudioDevice *audioDevice;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary *activeCallInvites;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary *activeCalls;

// activeCall represents the last connected call
@property (nonatomic, strong) TVOCall *activeCall;

@property (nonatomic, strong) CXProvider *callKitProvider;
@property (nonatomic, strong) CXCallController *callKitCallController;
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL userInitiatedDisconnect;

@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL playCustomRingback;
@property (nonatomic, strong) AVAudioPlayer *ringtonePlayer;


@end







//#import <React/RCTLog.h>

@implementation RCTCallPackageModule



-(NSString *)fetchAccessToken {
 NSString *accessToken = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://54.172.240.200:4000/accessToken"]
                          encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                           error:nil];

 return accessToken;
}

-(void) mainIntializerFunction {
 
  self.pushKitEventDelegate = self;

  
  self.callKitCallController = [[CXCallController alloc] init];
//    fetchData();
  /* Please note that the designated initializer `[CXProviderConfiguration initWithLocalizedName:]` has been deprecated on iOS 14. */
  CXProviderConfiguration *configuration = [[CXProviderConfiguration alloc] initWithLocalizedName:@"Voice Quickstart"];
  configuration.maximumCallGroups = 1;
  configuration.maximumCallsPerCallGroup = 1;
  
  self.callKitProvider = [[CXProvider alloc] initWithConfiguration:configuration];
  [self.callKitProvider setDelegate:self queue:nil];
  
 
  self.audioDevice = [TVODefaultAudioDevice audioDevice];
  TwilioVoiceSDK.audioDevice = self.audioDevice;

  
  self.activeCallInvites = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
  self.activeCalls = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
  
  
  self.playCustomRingback = NO;
  
  [self MainFunctionToCall];   }  
- (void)dealloc {
    if (self.callKitProvider) {
        [self.callKitProvider invalidate];
    } }
-(void) MainFunctionToCall {
  if (self.activeCall != nil) {
      self.userInitiatedDisconnect = YES;
      [self performEndCallActionWithUUID:self.activeCall.uuid];
  } else {
      NSUUID *uuid = [NSUUID UUID];
      NSString *handle = @"Voice Bot";
      
      [self checkRecordPermission:^(BOOL permissionGranted) {
              [center requestAuthorizationWithOptions:(UNAuthorizationOptionAlert + UNAuthorizationOptionSound)
                                    completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {
                                        // Enable or disable features based on authorization.
                                    }];
//              [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
              [self performStartCallActionWithUUID:uuid handle:handle];
          
      }];
    
  }
  
}


// performEndCallActiveUUID

- (void)performEndCallActionWithUUID:(NSUUID *)uuid {
    CXEndCallAction *endCallAction = [[CXEndCallAction alloc] initWithCallUUID:uuid];
    CXTransaction *transaction = [[CXTransaction alloc] initWithAction:endCallAction];

    [self.callKitCallController requestTransaction:transaction completion:^(NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"EndCallAction transaction request failed: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        }
        else {
          
        }
    }];
}


// checkRecordPermission

- (void)checkRecordPermission:(void(^)(BOOL permissionGranted))completion {
    AVAudioSessionRecordPermission permissionStatus = [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] recordPermission];
    switch (permissionStatus) {
        case AVAudioSessionRecordPermissionGranted:
            // Record permission already granted.
            completion(YES);
            break;
        case AVAudioSessionRecordPermissionDenied:
            // Record permission denied.
            completion(NO);
            break;
        case AVAudioSessionRecordPermissionUndetermined:
        {
            
            [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] requestRecordPermission:^(BOOL granted) {
                completion(granted);
            }];
            break;
        }
        default:
            completion(NO);
            break;
    }
}

#pragma mark - CallKit Actions
- (void)performStartCallActionWithUUID:(NSUUID *)uuid handle:(NSString *)handle {
    if (uuid == nil || handle == nil) {
        return;
    }


    CXHandle *callHandle = [[CXHandle alloc] initWithType:CXHandleTypeGeneric value:handle];
    CXStartCallAction *startCallAction = [[CXStartCallAction alloc] initWithCallUUID:uuid handle:callHandle];
    CXTransaction *transaction = [[CXTransaction alloc] initWithAction:startCallAction];

    [self.callKitCallController requestTransaction:transaction completion:^(NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"StartCallAction transaction request failed: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        } else {
         

            CXCallUpdate *callUpdate = [[CXCallUpdate alloc] init];
            callUpdate.remoteHandle = callHandle;
            callUpdate.supportsDTMF = YES;
            callUpdate.supportsHolding = YES;
            callUpdate.supportsGrouping = NO;
            callUpdate.supportsUngrouping = NO;
            callUpdate.hasVideo = NO;

            [self.callKitProvider reportCallWithUUID:uuid updated:callUpdate];
        }
    }];
}

#pragma mark - PushKitEventDelegate
- (void)credentialsUpdated:(PKPushCredentials *)credentials {
    NSData *cachedDeviceToken = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:kCachedDeviceToken];
    if ([self registrationRequired] || ![cachedDeviceToken isEqualToData:credentials.token]) {
        cachedDeviceToken = credentials.token;
        
        
        [TwilioVoiceSDK registerWithAccessToken:kAccessToken
                                    deviceToken:cachedDeviceToken
                                     completion:^(NSError *error) {
             if (error) {
               
             } else {
           
                 
                 // Save the device token after successfully registered.
                 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:cachedDeviceToken forKey:kCachedDeviceToken];
                 
                 
                 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSDate date] forKey:kCachedBindingTime];
             }
        }];
    }
}

- (BOOL)registrationRequired {
    BOOL registrationRequired = YES;
    NSDate *lastBindingCreated = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:kCachedBindingTime];
    
    if (lastBindingCreated) {
        NSDateComponents *dayComponent = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
        
        // Register upon half of the TTL
        dayComponent.day = kRegistrationTTLInDays / 2;
        
        NSDate *bindingExpirationDate = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateByAddingComponents:dayComponent toDate:lastBindingCreated options:0];
        NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
        if ([bindingExpirationDate compare:currentDate] == NSOrderedDescending) {
            registrationRequired = NO;
        }
    }
    return registrationRequired;
}

- (void)credentialsInvalidated {
    NSData *cachedDeviceToken = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:kCachedDeviceToken];
    if ([cachedDeviceToken length] > 0) {
        [TwilioVoiceSDK unregisterWithAccessToken:kAccessToken
                                      deviceToken:cachedDeviceToken
                                       completion:^(NSError *error) {
            if (error) {
         
            } else {
                
               
            }
        }];
    }

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:kCachedDeviceToken];
        
    // Remove the cached binding as credentials are invalidated
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:kCachedBindingTime];
}

-(void)incomingPushReceived:(PKPushPayload *)payload withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(void))completion {
    // The Voice SDK will use main queue to invoke `cancelledCallInviteReceived:error` when delegate queue is not passed
    if (![TwilioVoiceSDK handleNotification:payload.dictionaryPayload delegate:self delegateQueue:nil]) {
    
    }
    
    if (completion) {
        if ([[NSProcessInfo processInfo] operatingSystemVersion].majorVersion < 13) {
            // Save for later when the notification is properly handled.
            self.incomingPushCompletionCallback = completion;
        } else {
           
            completion();
        }
    }
}
- (void)incomingPushHandled {
    if (self.incomingPushCompletionCallback) {
        self.incomingPushCompletionCallback();
        self.incomingPushCompletionCallback = nil;
    }
}


#pragma mark - TVONotificationDelegate
- (void)callInviteReceived:(TVOCallInvite *)callInvite {
    
   


    
   
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSDate date] forKey:kCachedBindingTime];
    
    if (callInvite.callerInfo.verified != nil && [callInvite.callerInfo.verified boolValue]) {
       
    }
    
    NSString *from = @"Voice Bot";
    if (callInvite.from) {
        from = [callInvite.from stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"client:" withString:@""];
    }
    
    // Always report to CallKit
    [self reportIncomingCallFrom:from withUUID:callInvite.uuid];
    self.activeCallInvites[[callInvite.uuid UUIDString]] = callInvite;
    if ([[NSProcessInfo processInfo] operatingSystemVersion].majorVersion < 13) {
        [self incomingPushHandled];
    }
}
- (void)cancelledCallInviteReceived:(TVOCancelledCallInvite *)cancelledCallInvite error:(NSError *)error {
    TVOCallInvite *callInvite;
    for (NSString *uuid in self.activeCallInvites) {
        TVOCallInvite *activeCallInvite = [self.activeCallInvites objectForKey:uuid];
        if ([cancelledCallInvite.callSid isEqualToString:activeCallInvite.callSid]) {
            callInvite = activeCallInvite;
            break;
        }
    }
    
    if (callInvite) {
        [self performEndCallActionWithUUID:callInvite.uuid];
        [self.activeCallInvites removeObjectForKey:callInvite.uuid.UUIDString];
    }
}


- (void)callDidStartRinging:(TVOCall *)call {
    NSLog(@"callDidStartRinging:");
  
    if (self.playCustomRingback) {
        [self playRingback];
    }
    
//    [self.placeCallButton setTitle:@"Ringing" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}

- (void)callDidConnect:(TVOCall *)call {
    NSLog(@"callDidConnect:");
    
    if (self.playCustomRingback) {
        [self stopRingback];
    }
  [self sendEventWithName:@"onSessionConnect" body:@"Connected"];
    self.callKitCompletionCallback(YES);
    
    
    
}


- (void)call:(TVOCall *)call isReconnectingWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"Call is reconnecting");
    
}

- (void)callDidReconnect:(TVOCall *)call {
    NSLog(@"Call reconnected");

  
}

- (void)call:(TVOCall *)call didFailToConnectWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"Call failed to connect: %@", error);
    
    self.callKitCompletionCallback(NO);
    [self.callKitProvider reportCallWithUUID:call.uuid endedAtDate:[NSDate date] reason:CXCallEndedReasonFailed];
  [self sendEventWithName:@"onSessionConnect" body:@"Failure"];
    [self callDisconnected:call];
}

- (void)call:(TVOCall *)call didDisconnectWithError:(NSError *)error {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Call failed: %@", error);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Call disconnected");
    }

    if (!self.userInitiatedDisconnect) {
        CXCallEndedReason reason = CXCallEndedReasonRemoteEnded;
        if (error) {
            reason = CXCallEndedReasonFailed;
        }
        
        [self.callKitProvider reportCallWithUUID:call.uuid endedAtDate:[NSDate date] reason:reason];
    }
  [self sendEventWithName:@"onSessionConnect" body:@"Disconnected"];
    [self callDisconnected:call];
}

- (void)callDisconnected:(TVOCall *)call {
    if ([call isEqual:self.activeCall]) {
        self.activeCall = nil;
    }
    [self.activeCalls removeObjectForKey:call.uuid.UUIDString];
    
    self.userInitiatedDisconnect = NO;
    
    if (self.playCustomRingback) {
        [self stopRingback];
    }
    

}

- (void)call:(TVOCall *)call
didReceiveQualityWarnings:(NSSet<NSNumber *> *)currentWarnings
previousWarnings:(NSSet<NSNumber *> *)previousWarnings {
    /**
     * currentWarnings: existing quality warnings that have not been cleared yet
     * previousWarnings: last set of warnings prior to receiving this callback
     *
     * Example:
     *   - currentWarnings: { A, B }
     *   - previousWarnings: { B, C }
     *   - intersection: { B }
     *
     * Newly raised warnings = currentWarnings - intersection = { A }
     * Newly cleared warnings = previousWarnings - intersection = { C }
     */
    NSMutableSet *warningIntersetction = [currentWarnings mutableCopy];
    [warningIntersetction intersectSet:previousWarnings];
    
    NSMutableSet *newWarnings = [currentWarnings mutableCopy];
    [newWarnings minusSet:warningIntersetction];
    if ([newWarnings count] > 0) {
        [self qualityWarningUpdatePopup:newWarnings isCleared:NO];
    }
    
    NSMutableSet *clearedWarnings = [previousWarnings mutableCopy];
    [clearedWarnings minusSet:warningIntersetction];
    if ([clearedWarnings count] > 0) {
        [self qualityWarningUpdatePopup:clearedWarnings isCleared:YES];
    }
}
- (void)qualityWarningUpdatePopup:(NSSet *)warnings isCleared:(BOOL)cleared {
    NSString *popupMessage = (cleared)? @"Warnings cleared:" : @"Warnings detected:";
    for (NSNumber *warning in warnings) {
        NSString *warningName = [self warningString:[warning unsignedIntValue]];
        popupMessage = [popupMessage stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@" %@", warningName]];
    }
    

    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f
                     animations:^{
   
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(5.0f * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
            
            } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            
            }];
        });
    }];
}

- (NSString *)warningString:(TVOCallQualityWarning)qualityWarning {
    switch (qualityWarning) {
        case TVOCallQualityWarningHighRtt:
            return @"high-rtt";
            break;
        case TVOCallQualityWarningHighJitter:
            return @"high-jitter";
            break;
        case TVOCallQualityWarningHighPacketsLostFraction:
            return @"high-packets-lost-fraction";
            break;
        case TVOCallQualityWarningLowMos:
            return @"low-mos";
            break;
        case TVOCallQualityWarningConstantAudioInputLevel:
            return @"constant-audio-input-level";
            break;
        default:
            return @"Unknown warning";
            break;
    }
}
-(void)pushRegistry:(PKPushRegistry *)registry didReceiveIncomingPushWithPayload:(PKPushPayload *)payload forType:(NSString *)type {
   NSLog(@"pushRegistry:didReceiveIncomingPushWithPayload:forType:");
   if ([type isEqualToString:PKPushTypeVoIP]) {
       
       // The Voice SDK will use main queue to invoke `cancelledCallInviteReceived:error` when delegate queue is not passed
     if (![TwilioVoiceSDK handleNotification:payload.dictionaryPayload delegate:self delegateQueue:nil]) {
           NSLog(@"This is not a valid Twilio Voice notification.");
       }
     else
     {
       
     }
   }
}

/**
* This delegate method is available on iOS 11 and above. Call the completion handler once the
* notification payload is passed to the `TwilioVoice.handleNotification()` method.
*/
- (void)pushRegistry:(PKPushRegistry *)registry
didReceiveIncomingPushWithPayload:(PKPushPayload *)payload
            forType:(PKPushType)type
withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(void))completion {
   NSLog(@"pushRegistry:didReceiveIncomingPushWithPayload:forType:withCompletionHandler:");

   // Save for later when the notification is properly handled.
   self.incomingPushCompletionCallback = completion;

   
   if ([type isEqualToString:PKPushTypeVoIP]) {
       // The Voice SDK will use main queue to invoke `cancelledCallInviteReceived:error` when delegate queue is not passed
     if (![TwilioVoiceSDK handleNotification:payload.dictionaryPayload delegate:self delegateQueue:nil]) {
           NSLog(@"This is not a valid Twilio Voice notification.");
       }
   }
   if ([[NSProcessInfo processInfo] operatingSystemVersion].majorVersion < 13) {
       // Save for later when the notification is properly handled.
       self.incomingPushCompletionCallback = completion;
   } else {
       /**
       * The Voice SDK processes the call notification and returns the call invite synchronously. Report the incoming call to
       * CallKit and fulfill the completion before exiting this callback method.
       */
       completion();
   }
}

#pragma mark - AVAudioSession
- (void)toggleAudioRoute:(BOOL)toSpeaker {
    // The mode set by the Voice SDK is "VoiceChat" so the default audio route is the built-in receiver. Use port override to switch the route.
    self.audioDevice.block =  ^ {
        // We will execute `kDefaultAVAudioSessionConfigurationBlock` first.
        kTVODefaultAVAudioSessionConfigurationBlock();
        
        // Overwrite the audio route
        AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
        NSError *error = nil;
        if (toSpeaker) {
            if (![session overrideOutputAudioPort:AVAudioSessionPortOverrideSpeaker error:&error]) {
                NSLog(@"Unable to reroute audio: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
            }
        } else {
            if (![session overrideOutputAudioPort:AVAudioSessionPortOverrideNone error:&error]) {
                NSLog(@"Unable to reroute audio: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
            }
        }
    };
    self.audioDevice.block();
}

#pragma mark - CXProviderDelegate
- (void)providerDidReset:(CXProvider *)provider {
    NSLog(@"providerDidReset:");
    self.audioDevice.enabled = NO;
}

- (void)providerDidBegin:(CXProvider *)provider {
    NSLog(@"providerDidBegin:");
}

- (void)provider:(CXProvider *)provider didActivateAudioSession:(AVAudioSession *)audioSession {
    NSLog(@"provider:didActivateAudioSession:");
    self.audioDevice.enabled = YES;
}

- (void)provider:(CXProvider *)provider didDeactivateAudioSession:(AVAudioSession *)audioSession {
    NSLog(@"provider:didDeactivateAudioSession:");
    self.audioDevice.enabled = NO;
}

- (void)provider:(CXProvider *)provider timedOutPerformingAction:(CXAction *)action {
    NSLog(@"provider:timedOutPerformingAction:");
}

- (void)provider:(CXProvider *)provider performStartCallAction:(CXStartCallAction *)action {
    NSLog(@"provider:performStartCallAction:");
    
 
    
    [self.callKitProvider reportOutgoingCallWithUUID:action.callUUID startedConnectingAtDate:[NSDate date]];
    
    __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
    [self performVoiceCallWithUUID:action.callUUID client:nil completion:^(BOOL success) {
        __strong typeof(self) strongSelf = weakSelf;
        if (success) {
            NSLog(@"performVoiceCallWithUUID successful");
            [strongSelf.callKitProvider reportOutgoingCallWithUUID:action.callUUID connectedAtDate:[NSDate date]];
        } else {
            NSLog(@"performVoiceCallWithUUID failed");
        }
        [action fulfill];
    }];
}
- (void)provider:(CXProvider *)provider performAnswerCallAction:(CXAnswerCallAction *)action {
    NSLog(@"provider:performAnswerCallAction:");
    
    [self performAnswerVoiceCallWithUUID:action.callUUID completion:^(BOOL success) {
        if (success) {
            NSLog(@"performAnswerVoiceCallWithUUID successful");
        } else {
            NSLog(@"performAnswerVoiceCallWithUUID failed");
        }
    }];
    
    [action fulfill];
}

- (void)provider:(CXProvider *)provider performEndCallAction:(CXEndCallAction *)action {
    NSLog(@"provider:performEndCallAction:");
    
    TVOCallInvite *callInvite = self.activeCallInvites[action.callUUID.UUIDString];
    TVOCall *call = self.activeCalls[action.callUUID.UUIDString];

    if (callInvite) {
        [callInvite reject];
        [self.activeCallInvites removeObjectForKey:callInvite.uuid.UUIDString];
    } else if (call) {
        [call disconnect];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Unknown UUID to perform end-call action with");
    }

    [action fulfill];
}

- (void)provider:(CXProvider *)provider performSetHeldCallAction:(CXSetHeldCallAction *)action {
    TVOCall *call = self.activeCalls[action.callUUID.UUIDString];
    if (call) {
        [call setOnHold:action.isOnHold];
        [action fulfill];
    } else {
        [action fail];
    }
}

- (void)provider:(CXProvider *)provider performSetMutedCallAction:(CXSetMutedCallAction *)action {
    TVOCall *call = self.activeCalls[action.callUUID.UUIDString];
    if (call) {
        [call setMuted:action.isMuted];
        [action fulfill];
    } else {
        [action fail];
    }
}

#pragma mark - CallKit Actions


- (void)reportIncomingCallFrom:(NSString *) from withUUID:(NSUUID *)uuid {
    CXHandle *callHandle = [[CXHandle alloc] initWithType:CXHandleTypeGeneric value:from];

    CXCallUpdate *callUpdate = [[CXCallUpdate alloc] init];
    callUpdate.remoteHandle = callHandle;
    callUpdate.supportsDTMF = YES;
    callUpdate.supportsHolding = YES;
    callUpdate.supportsGrouping = NO;
    callUpdate.supportsUngrouping = NO;
    callUpdate.hasVideo = NO;

    [self.callKitProvider reportNewIncomingCallWithUUID:uuid update:callUpdate completion:^(NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            
        }
        else {
            
        }
    }];
}



- (void)performVoiceCallWithUUID:(NSUUID *)uuid
                          client:(NSString *)client
                      completion:(void(^)(BOOL success))completionHandler {
    __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
  

    TVOConnectOptions *connectOptions = [TVOConnectOptions optionsWithAccessToken:kAccessToken block:^(TVOConnectOptionsBuilder *builder) {
        __strong typeof(self) strongSelf = weakSelf;
      
    
      
      
        builder.params = @{kTwimlParamTo:phoneNumber};
      
        builder.uuid = uuid;
    }];
    TVOCall *call = [TwilioVoiceSDK connectWithOptions:connectOptions delegate:self];
    if (call) {
        self.activeCall = call;
        self.activeCalls[call.uuid.UUIDString] = call;
    }
    self.callKitCompletionCallback = completionHandler;
}

- (void)performAnswerVoiceCallWithUUID:(NSUUID *)uuid
                            completion:(void(^)(BOOL success))completionHandler {
    TVOCallInvite *callInvite = self.activeCallInvites[uuid.UUIDString];
    NSAssert(callInvite, @"No CallInvite matches the UUID");
    
    TVOAcceptOptions *acceptOptions = [TVOAcceptOptions optionsWithCallInvite:callInvite block:^(TVOAcceptOptionsBuilder *builder) {
        builder.uuid = callInvite.uuid;
    }];

    TVOCall *call = [callInvite acceptWithOptions:acceptOptions delegate:self];

    if (!call) {
        completionHandler(NO);
    } else {
        self.callKitCompletionCallback = completionHandler;
        self.activeCall = call;
        self.activeCalls[call.uuid.UUIDString] = call;
    }

    [self.activeCallInvites removeObjectForKey:callInvite.uuid.UUIDString];
    
    if ([[NSProcessInfo processInfo] operatingSystemVersion].majorVersion < 13) {
        [self incomingPushHandled];
    }
}

#pragma mark - Ringtone

- (void)playRingback {
    NSString *ringtonePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ringtone" ofType:@"wav"];
    if ([ringtonePath length] <= 0) {
       
        return;
    }
    
    NSError *error;
    self.ringtonePlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:ringtonePath] error:&error];
    if (error != nil) {
  
    } else {
        self.ringtonePlayer.delegate = self;
        self.ringtonePlayer.numberOfLoops = -1;
        
        self.ringtonePlayer.volume = 1.0f;
        [self.ringtonePlayer play];
    }
}

- (void)stopRingback {
    if (!self.ringtonePlayer.isPlaying) {
        return;
    }
    
    [self.ringtonePlayer stop];
}

- (void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag {
    if (flag) {
        NSLog(@"Audio player finished playing successfully");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Audio player finished playing with some error");
    }
}

- (void)audioPlayerDecodeErrorDidOccur:(AVAudioPlayer *)player error:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"Decode error occurred: %@", error);
}



@end
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say "it's not working"? Where does it fail? What actually happens? Are there any errors in your application, on your server or in the Twilio debugger? Do you give your access token the permission to `incomingAllow`?

Comment: hello. can you tell me where i can give access token  permission to incomingAllow?

Comment: When you create an Access Token on your server you give the `incomingAllow` permission. Check [the documentation and code sample here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/iam/access-tokens?code-sample=code-creating-an-access-token-voice&code-language=Python&code-sdk-version=7.x).

Comment: yeah we did that. i thought you were talking about give permission of access token within iOS objective c code.

Comment: Ok, so how about my other questions? How is it not working? What actually happens?

Comment: i added vOIP certificate in twilio console. added access token and did everything that was in twilio installation documentation. but when i call on twilio number from my personal number, nothing works, not even debugger runs.

Comment: Can you share the code you're using on the server to dial the client, the code that returns TwiML in the Twilio webhook? Does the identity in the TwiML match the identity in your access token?

Comment: Did you find any solutions for this? I'm having the same issue. Access token is created with incomingAllow permission. identity also matches with the TwiML response of the incoming call function. Call logs on the dashboard shows status as not answered.

Comment: @RyanAluvihare nope i didn't get any solution for this. Even the support wasn't able to help me out for this.

Comment: I actually got it to working today. I had missed the pushCredentialSid parameter on the VoiceGrant when creating the access token